# Two flot charts in adjoining HTML divs causing problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt, flot

I have written a jquery plugin that converts a HTML table into a chart using Flot. The HTML is generated from an XSLT and within the XSLT I have the following code to make a call to my plugin. This code attempts to display two charts side by side in the blah1 and blah2 HTML divs (one in each div):

```
<div id="blah1" style="width:50%;height:100px;float:left;position:relative; padding: 0px">
    <script language="javascript" defer="true">
        <xsl:comment>
            <![CDATA[$(document).ready($('#blah1').myPlugin()));]]>
        </xsl:comment>
    </script>
</div>

<div id="blah2" style="width:50%;height:100px;float:right;position:relative; padding: 0px">
    <script type="javascript" defer="true">
        <xsl:comment>
            <![CDATA[$(document).ready($('#blah2').myPlugin()));]]>
        </xsl:comment>
    </script>
</div>
```

There is a problem with the way the HTML is generated though when viewed through a browser. The left div (blah1) generated the HTML correctly, with the canvas elements and everything (and displays a chart in the browser) , however the right div(blah2) generates the following:

```
<script type="javascript" defer="true">
    <!--$(document).ready($('#blah2').myPlugin());   //-->
</script>
```

Any idea what is happening here? Why would one div work and the other not..? Also another strange thing is the chart that appears in blah1 is actually the one that should have appeared in blah2. The blah2 chart overwrites the chart drawn by the code in blah1. If I comment out the blah 2 jquery call, then the blah1 div correctly shows the expected chart.

Comment: The first thing that pop to my eyes is that the second script tag defines the attribute type="javascript" instead of type="text/javascript". BTW, the attribute language = "javascript" is deprecated so you should change it to type = "text/javascript".

Comment: Maybe this is just my own ignorance, but why are you commenting the CDATA section inside the javascript tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, I figured the problem... I had hard coded the value of the div to "blah1" inside the jquery custom plugin, so no matter what div I called the plugin code on it got applied to the same div everytime.This became obvious to me after 4 hours of sleep.. (I can't believe what sleep deprivation can make you do)

Answer (score 0):

As @PabloPozo said that it looks like that the language attribute is depreciated change both your script tags to

```
<script type="text/javascript" defer="true">

</script>
```